# Weird behavior when 2 functions are trying(?) to run at the same time

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

So I just finished my weak project which is a remote controlled car.

My problem is that when I press the button for going reverse (as an example) while the opposite action is currently in progress, going forwards the built_in led flashes in the exact same pattern when the Arduino is restarted (you know, pressing the reset button) and the car just stops and becomes responsive again after the led stops doing it's thing.

I believe the problem might be with the functions that I made, those being Forward(), Reverse(), Left(), Right(), Stop();

Note that if i press 5 (which translates to Stop() in this case) it is behaving as expected.

Here's the code: (functions at the bottom)

```
#include <IRremote.h>

const int RECV_PIN = 7;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

int IN1 = 12; 
int IN2 = 11; 
int IN3 = 10;
int IN4 = 9;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN4, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600); 

  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  irrecv.blink13(true);
}

void loop()
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)){
        Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
        switch(results.value){

          case 0xFF18E7: // in fata  - 2
          Forward();
          break;

          case 0xFF4AB5: // in spate - 8
          Reverse();
          break;

          case 0xFF10EF: //   stanga - 4
          Left();
          break;

          case 0xFF5AA5: //  dreapta - 6
          Right();
          break;

          case 0xFF38C7: //   stop  - 5
          Stop();
          break;

        }
        irrecv.resume();
  }
}


void Forward()
{
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  Serial.print("Motor 1 Forward");
  Serial.println();

  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);  
  Serial.println("Motor 2 Forward");
  Serial.println();
}

void Reverse()
{
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
  Serial.print("Motor 1 Reverse");
  Serial.println();

  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
  Serial.println("Motor 2 Reverse");
  Serial.println();
}

void Left()
{
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  Serial.print("Motor 1 Reverse");
  Serial.println();

  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
  Serial.println("Motor 2 Forward");
  Serial.println();
}

void Right()
{
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
  Serial.print("Motor 1 Forward");
  Serial.println();

  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
  Serial.println("Motor 2 Reverse");
  Serial.println();
}

void Stop()
{
    digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
    Serial.print("Motor 1 Stop");
    Serial.println();

    digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
    Serial.println("Motor 2 Stop");
    Serial.println();

}
```

Comment: How are you powering the setup?

Comment: lol ... did you mean `week project`, as in seven day project, instead of `weak project` as in wimpy project?

Comment: the power supply may be getting shorted for the time needed to run this command `Serial.print();`   .... make sure that IN1 and IN2 actually control one motor